# Rails4 : find or create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I my rails app I have a autocomplete for users where they can chose their Company or put a new company i have also a company controller but don't want a company that doesn't exist in the automplete to be accessible in the company show page, i want something like linkedin when a user put a company that doesn't exist it will not be created but will be in the profil actually my code is like this

```
def company_name
  company.try(:name)
end

def company_name=(name)
  self.company = Company.find_or_initialize_by(name: name) if name.present?
end

<%= f.label :company_name, class: "jobs-newtitles" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Company.order(:name).map(&:name) },required: true,:autocomplete => :off, class: "form-control form-newjob" %>
```

i have tried to change `Company.find_or_initialize_by` to `Company.find_by` but that doesn't work, Anybody can guide me in how can I achieve this

Comment: Have you tried find_by_name? find by it self looks for id, and find_by_name should work

Comment: @NickCatib `find_by_name` and all `find_by_*` are deprecated. Use `find_by(name: name)`

Comment: Yeah, my fault... DickieBoy solution is much better. Post it as an answer :)

Comment: I already tried this but the problem that doesn't show name of a company if i put a new company

Comment: @NickCatib that is not the problem.

Comment: @DickieBoy `find_by_name` is not depreciated. See [Rails 4 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations). Excerpt: **"All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated"**. This has been going around a lot so I try to point it out to everyone when I can. Many dynamic finders have been depreciated but `find_by_...` is not one of them. `find_all_by_...` though has been along with a few others.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the info. Any reason why they were kept in? Seems silly to deprecate some but not all.

Comment: @DickieBoy I don't have an explicit reason that would be a question for the Rails Devs but it might have something to do with the fact that these methods produce an instance of an object where as many of the depreciated methods can be rewritten using where clauses producing an ActiveRecord::Relation instead. I think the `find_or_initialize_by_...` and `find_or_create_by_...` were depreciated because using `find_by()` in conjunction with `first_or_[initialize/create]` produces the same results and `find_or_[create/initialize]_by()` are far more flexible. But these are just suppositions.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is on how to design the system as you describe then I can see at least two options

- Add more metadata to the `Company` model

Add `has_profile` to `Company` and only set it to false for companies that are created through user association. Then filter for it accordingly wherever you need. Taking care of the filtering can be a bit painful depending on how your domain works, and I'd suggest staying away from default scopes.

- Work with a different model for the associated company

`User` has many `AssociatedCompany` which can have their own data like name and size, and may belong to a `Company`. If `AssociatedCompany` belongs to a `Company`, then you can pull the data like name from `Company` by defining methods in it that check if it's present, and if not use the name property in the `AssociatedCompany`.

From a code standpoint, for Rails 4, I'd recommend using

```
Model.where(name: name).first_or_initialize
# or
Model.where(name: name).first_or_create
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create